# moving conText commands into luacode environment

Tags: context

I am trying to figure out how to move some context commands inside a Lua environment.
(I am trying to create a document where most of the content is created dynamically from data pulled from an external source)

I have created this very simple MWE in normal context that works as expected

```
\defineexternalfigure
    [svgframe][method=svg, conversion=mp, width=10cm, height=10cm]
\defineoverlay
    [boxframe][{\externalfigure[frame.svg][svgframe][width=10cm,height=10cm]}]
    
\defineframed
    [CARDFRAME][height=10cm, width=10cm, frame=off, align=inner, background=boxframe]
\starttext
\CARDFRAME{\blank\blank Hello World!}
\stoptext
```

I'm using an arbitrary CC0 svg frame for the MWE [from here](https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/221284/rectangle-frame)

In attempting to convert the ordinary conText code.
I created this:

```
\startluacode

context.defineexternalfigure({ "svgframe" }, {method = "svg", conversion = "mp", width = "10cm" , height = "10cm" })
context.defineoverlay({ "boxframe" }, context.externalfigure( { "frame.svg" }, { "svgframe" } ) )
context.defineframed({ "CARDFRAME" }, {height = "10cm", width = "10cm", frame = "off", align = "inner", background = boxframe})
context.starttext()

context.CARDFRAME( context("Hello World") )

context.stoptext()
\stopluacode
```

There are at least two problems with this code that I can't figure out.

1. as it is written, I get the error: `tex error > tex error on line 1 in file : You can't use '\end' in internal vertical mode` during compilation
2. If I remove the `context.CARDFRAME(` and the matching closing bracket, then the compilation is successful, but the image seems to be typeset at the time of the defineoverlay.

on page 29 of [ConTEXt Lua Documents](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf) a situation is discussed that I think is similar, and adapting the solution given there, I think I would write the defineoverlay command as:

```
context.defineoverlay({ "boxframe" }, function() context.externalfigure( { "frame.svg" }, { "svgframe" } ) end )
```

but even when I do that, the image still seems to be typeset at the time of the defineoverlay command.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction in solving these issues?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

> 1. As it is written, I get the error:
>
>    ```
>    tex error > tex error on line 1 in file : You can't use '\end' in internal vertical mode
>    ```
>
>    during compilation

`context.stoptext()` ends the entire compilation run, but at that point the `luacode` environment is still open, so this won't work.

One option is to place the `\starttext`/`\stoptext` around the `\startluacode`/`\stopluacode`:

```tex
% test.tex
\starttext
\startluacode
    context("Hello World")
\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

but a better option is to place the *contents* of `\startluacode`/`\stopluacode` into a `.cld` file, which ConTeXt will process as Lua directly:

```lua
-- test.tex
context.starttext()
context("Hello World")
context.stoptext()
```

> 2. If I remove the `context.CARDFRAME(` and the matching closing bracket, then the compilation is successful, but the image seems to be typeset at the time of the `\defineoverlay`.
>
>    On page 29 of ConTEXt Lua Documents a situation is discussed that I think is similar, and adapting the solution given there, I think I would write the defineoverlay command as:
>
>    ```tex
>    context.defineoverlay({ "boxframe" }, function() context.externalfigure( { "frame.svg" }, { "svgframe" } ) end )
>    ```
>
>    but even when I do that, the image still seems to be typeset at the time of the `defineoverlay` command.

You're writing `context.defineoverlay({"first"}, "second")`, which is serialized as `\defineoverlay[first]{second}`, which ConTeXt ultimately processes as `\defineoverlay[first]` (a command with one argument) followed by `second` (the raw text).

To make this work, you need to wrap the function in `{`braces`}`:

```lua
context.defineexternalfigure(
    { "svgframe" },
    {
        method = "svg",
        conversion = "mp",
        width =
        "10cm",
        height = "10cm",
    }
)

context.defineoverlay(
    { "boxframe" },
    { -- Braces needed here since it's `\defineoverlay[...][...]`, not `\defineoverlay[...]{...}`.
        function ()  -- Wrap with a function here as you suggested
            context.externalfigure({ "frame.svg" }, { "svgframe" })
            return true  -- We need to return `true` here for weird caching reasons that only apply to this specific macro (and a few other rare cases that you probably won't run into).
        end
    }
)

context.defineframed(
    { "CARDFRAME" },
    {
        height = "10cm",
        width = "10cm",
        frame = "off",
        align = "inner",
        background = "boxframe", -- Quotes needed here since `boxframe` refers to the Lua variable which is undefined and therefore `nil`.
    }
)
context.startTEXpage()
context.CARDFRAME(function() -- Use a function so we can add the `\blank`s from the original example.
    context.blank()
    context.blank()
    context("Hello World")
end)
context.stopTEXpage()
```

[image: sample output]